# Loop to repeat an action when the mouse is clicked

Tags: java, loops

I am making a connect 4 game and I have that is on click as follows.

```
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    xPos = e.getX();
    yPos = e.getY();
    this.repaint();

    x = e.getX(); 
    if(x <= 400) { 
        x = x/48; 
        System.out.println("Column number " + x);
        positions[0][0]=1;
        Component board = e.getComponent();
    }
}
```

I then have a method that creates a red circle on the grid as follows

```
    public void fillCircle(Graphics g) {
    {
        g.setColor(Color.red);
        g.fillOval(xPos,yPos,40,40);
    }
}
```

However only one circle appears on click and when you re-click the circle is removed and is placed in the new position.

I believe I need to include some kind of loop on the fill circle method so that it doesnt just get rid of the circle and put onew in the new location, but it leaves it there and puts a new circle in the new place?

How would I do this?

Comment: I'm no GUI expert but I think that `repaint()` makes your first circle disappear, you need to keep track of all of them and draw them again on each `repaint()`

Answer (score 4):

You need to add the positions to an `ArrayList` or something because you're just overriding the variables `xPos` and `yPos` when you click. We can create a `Position` class to hold both x and y values so we only need one `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
    positions.add(new Position(e.getX(), e.getY()));

    // ...
}
```

And the `Position` class

```
class Position {
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public Position(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }
}
```

Then draw all the circles in your function

```
public void fillCircle(Graphics g) {
{
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)
        g.fillOval(positions.get(i).x, positions.get(i).y, 40, 40);
}
```

### Update

Include this at the very top of the file.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

This will import the ArrayList library that you want to use.

Comment: I get the error message cannot find symbol class ArrayList, How would I go about resolving this issue

Comment: Did you put a space in between Array and List? They need to be one word. I didn't use the symbol `Array` in my code.

Comment: That is with ArrayList, the same as above

Comment: Can you paste in the line of code that the compiler is complaining about?

Comment: ArrayList<Position> positions = new ArrayList<Position>();

Comment: Cannot find symbol - class ArrayList

Comment: I also in fillCircle get the error message cannot find symbol method size()

Comment: for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i++)

Comment: it's `positions.get(i)` and not `positions[i]`

Comment: The error I have is in the second line of fillCircle? I believe that is the third

Comment: I believe this means that I am missing a size method, Can anybody help me write the size method

Comment: I'm not sure, it's a member of ArrayList, see doco http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html